# Why are strawberries cooled before planting, and what is a term for this procedure?

Tags: planting, strawberries, terminology, technique

I've heard that it's a practice to cool strawberry plants to a low temperature (~2 °C/~35 °F) for some time before planting them. Supposedly this results in an increased growth tempo of the plants in good weather.

What is this method called (so I can learn more about it) and why is it useful?

Comment: For seeds it's commonly called "stratification" or cold stratification - same basic idea where some plants need to know that it's been winter before they will take off and grow (or sprout, in the case of seeds.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chill conditioning or chill requirement. Certain plants need certain hours of chill time to increase production. For those plants you need to get the right amount to strike a good balance between vegetative growth and fruit production. Good info on [chill conditioning strawberries here](http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=722).

Comment: Yup, strawberries need artificial cooling, if the conditions are unnaturally warm for the plants. Many plants are this way, sometimes for flower production (like blueberries), sometimes as a clearly defined dormant period for the plant (which is why many temperate perennials make poor house plants).